# Javascript Arguments Preference

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, styles, arguments

Just a style question.

do you people prefer to pass in variables into a function like

```
function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}(1,2);

or 

function (args){
    return args.a + args.b;
}({a:1;b:2});
```

?

Are there any performance issues between the two?

I'm deciding on standardizing my functions in some way, therefore I'm asking this question.

Comment: if you have optional arguments, use the second one. otherwise use the first.

Comment: This kind of question should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't know theres a separate stack exchange for code style! I'll check it out there next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a few parameters I would use the first for better readability (documentation).

If there are a lot of parameters, I would use the second one (for example options object).

I don't think there's any major performance difference between the two.

Comment: I was thinking of using the second one in the case that I need to extend my code or allow someone to perform a function overload.

Comment: Agreed, although I usually do the first because if someone else is implementing the function they might not know exactly what to expect when you pass an object (in javascript).

Comment: Generally, I've been writing code to be reused as libraries: aka Revealing Module Pattern. I'm organizing my vanilla javascript to be used later extensively.

Comment: Hmm, but if I do write comments to specify what someone needs to pass in, will that be an alternative?

Comment: @blinkomania Yeah, that would be an alternative, just keep in mind that you always have a second place you need to update with new changes (the comments), but it's really not that big of a deal. You could also combine the two.

Comment: Haha, dang! I'm still split between the two types. I know the first would be helpful in terms of readability, but even so I would need to still tell users what to pass in (apart from having really descriptive meaningful variable names). The second would be even harder to know what is required.

Answer (score 2):

I find it to be completely situational as to which style to use. I don't think anyone would argue that the first method is the most preferred and best for readability and would recommend this for most all functions.

I prefer to add in properties like in your second style when dealing with JSON data and using things like models in Backbone.

In terms of performance, the first style is faster.

I cleaned up your functions and added them to a test you can view here:

http://jsperf.com/declared-args-vs-lookup

Comment: Oh wow, that was fast! So if I want to allow my functions to have some kind of an overload system to it, is it better to use the 2nd code then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to worry about performance here. Even if there are some differences, they woudn't be critical for regular scripts.

As to coding style I'm all about using the first version (passing fixed number of arguments) for as long as you are certain of how the function api should look like (also it will be easier for other people to get idea of what are certain arguments for).

If the function is suppose to act like a entry point to your plugin use a second approach - it will be much easier to add/substract options that may be passed in object to that function, hence the API wouldn't change that much for people that are already using the script.

Comment: Hmm lets say I'm writing an extension of the above code add to have it take in 2 or 3 parameters add(a,b,c) and add(a,b). Would the second approach be better?

Comment: In that case (which is simple) I would still go with first approach - for it is more natural. You can easily act on number and type of arguments passed to `add` function without sacrificing readability.

Comment: Is there a style guide that I can follow for these kinds of nuances in javascript?

Comment: you can't go wrong with -> https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/

Comment: Woah, thats too much good stuff :P I'll check it out!